# Not Answered & Solved Question?

Tags: feature-request, answers

I have seen many questions in Stack Overflow which are unanswered or answers that do not provide solutions. When I need a solution for something, I have been stuck because there's no solution there. Even when the answerer got many upvotes, and I decided to try the solution, they have mostly not worked.

What exactly should the community do to unanswered or unsolved questions?
Is there a specific community legally authorized by this site to review and answer such questions for others to get valid references?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking here. What exactly should the community do to unanswered questions?

Comment: I *think* the question being asked *may* be "How to get experts to answer unanswered questions?"

Comment: yes @PolyGeo, it could be like that. pls let me know

Comment: absolutely yes @BradLarson

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize that you seem to be asking a question about how Stack Overflow works on Meta Stack Exchange (this site) instead of Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: so, I should ask this in Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: i don't think it is duplicate since I'm not the OP to ask twice. those questions belongs to many users in Stack Overflow about a year or more. It's like a spam for me when no solution found there. perhaps my question has the same as many others but they don't know how to start to ask about it (just like me)

Comment: Lolz this duplicate> How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions? looks joke really. That's not what I mean actually. please be fair. otherwise, you'll find this site fully spammed by others if you see this in your own view.

Comment: So, the experts here is to mark and flag? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly should the community do to unanswered or unsolved questions?

Well, the community (or those who need rep) could click on their favorite badge to reach all questions with that badge then clicking the unanswered tab. Any unanswered question or question with answers with scores less that 1 will show up. It will be up to those users to answer or not. The OP himself/herself could set up a bounty to attract more users and possibly more answers.

> Is there a specific community legally authorized by this site to review and answer such questions for others to get valid references?

That might reference to community wiki posts but are mainly in the meta sites. Jon Skeet's question about the correct number for C (link later) seems to be like this. The whole community is here to help the OP and future users get references to solve their problems. So the only community here is all of us users. Nothing else.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. 
"The whole community is here to help the OP and future users get references to solve their problems", I agree this, mate .. that's what I'm thinking that the site is to ask and answer, this sometimes will make user satisfied of the answer or vice verse. and you're right "So the only community here is all of us users. Nothing else."

thanks anyway :D

Comment: But, I think, this big site must have a specific team to collect (at least to filter) or give to community to be able to answer to very-old-QA then updated in home page question, from there, other user can give voting. If it is true based on users in site's decision then the answer got it and it's solved in at last. That would be very useful references right?